# lvalue required as left operand of assignment Error

Tags: c++

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I am getting the above error when I try to compile this piece of code:

Declaration of `bullets`:

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To explain the error message: The compiler complains that `&(*i) = ...` makes no sense: `&(*i)` is an address and cannot be changed.

For the fix, see fontanini's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Bullets contains `Part`s, not `Part*`. You also can't modify the memory address of the `Part` objects stored in your list, you can modify their contents.

You could use a list of pointers:

```
std::list<Part*> bullets;
/* ... */
*i = new BrokenPart(**i);
```

Note the two derreference operators on the iterator, once to get the `Part` pointer, and then another to derreference it.

As an advice, i would tell to to change your design. It looks like that `Part` class could be redesigned using the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), you should have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct `new BrokenPart` on a pre-allocated memory where object that `i` points to is stored, you could use **placement new** operator: `new (&(*i)) BrokenPart();`

Check out this question: [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222557/1168156)